# PHP Loop-Array concept converted to iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, arrays

I have This PHP Code With Arrays And Loops, Trying to convert it into Objective-c "iOS"

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
  $data[$item[date]][]=$var;
}
```

What i did so far is :

```
for(id theKey in result)
{
  leEvent[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theKey objectForKey:@"event_date"]]]=@"asd";
}
```

but it still overlaps each other if same key.
So any Idea ? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

I have this JSON:

> [{"id":"1","title":"test","event_date":"2014-01-28","description":"this
>   is a test desc ","time_stamp":"2014-01-28
>   13:04:12"},{"id":"2","title":"test2","event_date":"2014-01-29","description":"this
>   is a test desc2 ","time_stamp":"2014-01-28
>   13:21:36"},{"id":"3","title":"test3","event_date":"2014-01-29","description":"this
>   is a test desc3","time_stamp":"2014-01-28 13:21:36"}]

I want To make out of it Array That They key of Array is the Date : and inside each date other information
Expmple $data['2014-01-29'] should have 2 arrays in side it but i want to do it in iOS

Comment: post your nslog or output

Comment: in your php what you have trying

Comment: i'm not clear your question

Comment: @iDev The question is Clear , See The PHP Code, I'm trying to make same code but in iOS.

Comment: you want date is separated array is it in your json

Comment: @iDev i want the date to be as associative array key "NSDictionary Key" and each Array/NSDictionary with the Key(Date) to have arrays of the other information.

Comment: statically show your excepted output

Comment: lets assume arr is Array so :arr['2014-01-28']=((1,'test','this is a test desc')) arr['2014-01-29']=((2,'test2','this is a test desc2'),(3,'test3','this is a test desc3')) @iDev

Answer (score 1):

We have **"for in"** loop in objective C

For example:

```
for( NSNumber *num in numArray)
{
//Write your code here
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you want or you need some more info

**Update:**

You don't need a ForLoop in here.

Let's say `result` is your NSDictionary object.

So,

```
[result objectForKey:@"event_date"]
```

will give object for key "event_date".

By your code.. It seems like you are trying to set value for the key "event_date".

So your code would be something like this,

```
[result setObject:@"asd" forKey:@"event_date"];
```

Let me know if it does not help.

Comment: what is the Class of theKey? Can you tell exactly what you are trying to achieve here? @iJazJaz

Comment: Result is JSON Converted to NSDictionary so the key is the key of The Items in Dictionary

Comment: i exactly want to write this <code>$data[$item[date]][]=$var;</code> from php to Objective-c

Comment: its not about getting the items i want to group any thing of same date in same array

Comment: Check the new Update.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use JSONSerialization. This might ease up your task.

```
NSError* err = nil;

NSString* myJSONFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFileName" ofType:@"json"];

NSArray* dataTypes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myJSONFile] options:kNilOptions error:&err];

NSLog(@"Imported data Types: %@", dataTypes);
//This will print the data you just imported..

NSMutableArray *myArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[dataTypes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if([obj objectForKey:@"event_date"] isEqualTo:@"myDate")
    {
        [myArray addObject:obj];
    }

}];
```

I've checked this code... Working fine.. Let me know if any issues are there